# scrollview inside tabhost, tab2 disables button in tab1

Tags: android, scrollview, android-tabhost

iv'e got a bit of strange problem. I have a tabhost with 3 diffrent tabs.

tab1: a large button 
tab2: very much text (that needed a scrollview to see all)
tab3: just a litte text

so when i implemented the scrollview within tab2 it disabled the button in tab1...

and this little scroll icon to the right is shown even i tab1 and tab3 even tho they cannot be scrolled. But if i scroll in tab1 or tab3 the tab2 will be scrolled.

heres a example of my code lineup:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/carbonfibre"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="95dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/headerwithtext" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bRingTaxi"
                    android:layout_width="275dp"
                    android:layout_height="275dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_callcab"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick = "minKlass"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ScrollView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/scroller"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                     >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="15dp"
                        android:text="blahblahblah"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and then comes the third tab with similar attributes as tab1.
Does someone have a clue why this scrollview in tab2 disables my button in tab1 and why i can scroll the 2nd tab when im in tab1 and tab2?

best regards Razz

Comment: alright so i read somewhere that the scrollview will consumes all of it childs "functions" such as buttons. Is there some way to disable this within my tab1?

Comment: just figured out that when i but the button in my tab2 the button works perfect, so i think now the issue is to get the scrollview to JUST operate within tab2 and not affect the other tabs...

Comment: i got it! there has to be a LinearLayout to frame the tab, then the scrollview and then another LinearLayout to frame what the scrollview is working in :D

Comment: thanks that worked for me as well, even though Android calls one of the LinearLayouts useless.